# compile GWT failed - No source code is available for type

Tags: java, gwt

I have 2 modules: GWT and Java(SPring etc).
Little explanation: In Java module I have a Java Mail Sender method which I want to use in my GWT Widget. That's method has 2 parameters: `java.util.List<User> recipients` and `String message`.
 There is an example

```
Project
  -GWT
  -Java(Spring and etc)
```

What I need(Here you may see my attempts and below will be code what I have):
**1)**I want to call java method in my class which was inherited on Composite class. Then I got the following error:
`No source code is available for type my.packet.proj.MyClass; did you forget to inherit a required module?`
**2)**I learned that it's not possible to call the Java code (not all) in GWT, and I used JSNI(I wrote some native methods) to realize that, but it was impossible to me, unfortunately...
There is a code example that I had have.

```
public class MyClass extends Composite{

   @UiField
   TextBox text;

   @UiField
   Button btn;



   interface EmailMailingUiBinder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, MyClass> {
   }

   private static MyClassUiBinder myUiBinder = GWT.create(MyClassUiBinder.class);
   /*@param mailService is an object of messaging class in Java module*/

   public MyClass(MailService mailService){
     btn.addClickHandler( (event) ->{

     sendOnClick(mailService, recipients ,message); //code below
    });

    public native void sendOnClick(MailService mailService, List<User> recipients,   String msg)/*-{
       mailService.@my.packet.proj.MailService::sendMessage(Ljava/util/List,/*and so on*/)(recipients, msg)
     }-*/
}
```

There was no errors in code above when Gradle compile Gwt. But I need  to call it class(because it's widget, page) in MainPanel, when I create an instance of MyClass, like this: `new MyClass(new MailService())` compileGwt FAILED with compilation errors

```
No source code is available for type my.packet.proj.MailService; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Guys, do you have any idea how to pass instance as a argument?

P.S. I removed some unnecessary code 
P.S.S I even tried like that(to create my Instance of MyClass):

```
new MyClass(mailServiceInstance());

/*and anywhere below*/
//this is a X line below, for explanation
public native MailService mailServiceInstance()/*-{
        return @my.packet.proj.MailService::new()();
    }-*/;
```

I have the same error on line X

```
No source code is available for type my.packet.proj.MailService; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Comment: Why don't you use RPC for mail sending? It's actually not a client task to do. As for `no source code` error. In order to use something in client code, you have to make GWT compiler see it so that it could translate it into JS. This is done by adding `<source>` tags into gwt.xml file.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov as I understood to solve my problem I just havev to `<source path"my.packet.proj" />` into gwt.xml file? Or do I still have to use RPC? if yes, could you could you give an example to use RPC in my case? Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the main foundation of GWT, GWT is run in client, it means pure javascript running in a browser. So each java code you want to compile into javascript must be written knowing that the runtime is a browser with a lot of limitations and not the standard JVM.

You want to run a class to send emails which has been thought to be run in the JVM, probably your `my.packet.proj.MyClass` wants to open sockets to connect to a smtp server etc, which is impossible to be emulated in JS because you cannot open a normal socket against that server. This is just an example of a large list of limitations you have in client side.

So, all the java code which can be run in client comes from gwt compliant libraries, this code has been written in java for gwt, or may be some code could be written in java initially and ported to gwt. These libraries delivered in .jar files has to include it's module definitions (gwt.xml) to inherit in your project, the original java source code,  etc. In fact the byte code (.class) files are not used by the GWT compiler, although it could be needed in IDE's etc.

Said that, in order to use any java code not written for GWT, you have to either:

1. port it to GWT creating a .gwt.xml file which you have to inherit, validating previously that all the code does not break browser limitations, does not depend on non gwt 3party libraries, etc.
2. run it in server side, and make ajax calls from the browser.

So in your case the easiest way and I guess the only way, is that you include the `my.packet.proj.MyClass` in your .war, and create a [RPC service](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) (or any ajax solution) which you use from the client side to sent the mail.