# GWT RPC can't instatiate class on server side

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I had some problems with GWT, but I decided - use one of the tips given to me in my [quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791189/compile-gwt-failed-no-source-code-is-available-for-type)

But now I have another problem: I try realize GWT RPC.
What I have done: I wrote my own class instance of that I passing from client to server

```
class MyDataClass implements Serializable{}
```

Also, I created other classes(interface): `interface MsgRPC extends RemoteService{} and         public interface MsgRPCAsync`

Finally, I implemented my interface:

```
class MessageRPCImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MsgRpc{}
```

What I want: 
I can't instantiate `MessageSender class` in `MessageRPCImpl` because `MessageSender` isn't Serializable, but because MessageRPCImpl located on server-side, Could I do that, Isn't it?
Or how I can call message function in servlet class?

Anybody could help me?

Comment: What is exactly the `MessageSender` class? You didn't introduce it but you talk about wanting to instantiating it and using it...

Comment: @icza it's my own class, that's written with using Spring,Freemarker and JavaMail

Comment: Can you show us its source or at least its skeleton?

Comment: @icza something like that: http://pastebin.com/nL4HQK5V , when I try intantiate this class in my RPC servlet I get Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String package.client.util.MessageRemoteService.message(package.client.util.CustomMessageObjectData)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I can't access pastebin.com (blocked). Just edit your answer.